# Check whether the XML has more than one IDREF, add a comma in the XSLT if it does

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to ask how to make an XSLT stylesheet add a comma to the output if my XML input contain two or more IDREFs at a given point.  For example if the XML has:

```
<person unique_no="p2" gender = "M">
    <chef-ref IDREF="c2"/>
    <chef-ref IDREF="c1"/>
</person>
<doctor id="c1">
    <d_f_name>Chef Linguini</d_f_name>
    <d_l_name>Gusteau</d_l_name>
    <specification>&on;</specification>
</doctor>

<doctor id="c2">
    <d_f_name>Gordon</d_f_name>
    <d_l_name>Ramsay</d_l_name>
    <specification>&ENT;</specification>
</doctor>
```

As you can see, in the XML document above, I have two IDREFs on the `chef-ref` children of the `person` element.

How do I make the XSLT stylesheet include a comma in the output in this case?

Does the XSLT need to be something like this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="person">
  <td>
    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="key('Medications', @Medications/@IDREF)"/>
    -->
    <xsl:value-of select="@doctor"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Can you share the required output? The code shared has `@doctor` nested in the `for-each` loop for `<person>` which is incorrect. As per the input XML `<doctor>` is a sibling of `<person>` and not an attribute of `<person>`. For checking an occurrence of a node or attribute, you can use the `count()` function.

Comment: Please check the solution for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679909/how-to-link-idref-from-xml-to-xslt). I believe it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please always say which XSLT version you are using. XSLT 1.0 is now ancient history but a surprising number of people still use it.

In XSLT 2.0 this is very easy, you just do

```
<xsl:value-of select="person/@doctor" separator=", "/>
```

In XSLT 1.0 you have to do roughly what you are doing in your example. However, it's better to insert a separator before every item except the first (`test="position()!=1"`), rather than after every item except the last. That's because knowing whether you're at the end of the list involves look-ahead, which can be expensive.